# How to list the latest 5 entries per entry type?

Tags: entries, entry-type

Let's say I have 4 entry types (Article, Video, Photo & Quote). What's the best way to list the latest 5 entries by each entry type?

Answer (score 8):

[craft.entries()](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries) fetches entries.

To fetch the entries with a given entry type, you use [type](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#type). So to get the *Article* entries, either `craft.entries.type('Article')` or `craft.entries({type: 'Article'})`

To fetch the latest 5, you want the entries [sorted](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#order) by postDate, descending (this is the default sort order), and then [limit](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/craft.entries#limit) that to 5. Combining with the entry type, you have: `craft.entries.type('Article').limit(5)` or `craft.entries({type: 'Article', limit: 5})`

And you have four entry types, so might as well loop over those:

```
{% for entryType in ['Article', 'Video', 'Photo', Quote] %}
  {% set latestFive = craft.entries({
    type: entryType,
    limit: 5
  }) %}

  {% for oneEntry in latestFive %}
    {# list that entry #}
    {{ oneEntry.title}} is of type {{ entryType }}
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```